Pass Json from Zod instance with references
I want to be able to

create and send a Zod instance as a serialized JSON.
receive such a JSON and parse it back to a Zod instance.

Problem: On the receiving part using Zod Schema parse throws error
ZodError: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "object",
    "path": [
      0,
      "parents",
      0
    ],
    "message": "Expected string, received object"
  },

Workaround:
Sending part:
Remap all references as Zod expects those to be list of string ids instead of objects.
export async function GET() {
    const dbPersons = await getCollection("person");
    const persons = dbPersons.map((dbPerson) => {
        // Only this line causes the error above
        return dbPerson.data;
        // Workaround which works
        const parents = dbPerson.data.parents?.map(parent => parent.id);
        const children = dbPerson.data.children?.map(child => child.id);
        const spouses = dbPerson.data.spouses?.map(spouse => spouse.id);
        return Object.assign({}, {
            ...dbPerson.data,
            parents,
            children,
            spouses
        });
    });
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(persons));
}

Receiving part:
const personAPIResp = await personsApi.json();
const persons = await ZPersonArray.parseAsync(personAPIResp);

Affected part of the schema:
export const ZPerson = z.object({
    id: z.number({
        message: "Unique identifier of a person"
    }),
    // ...
    // Parents
    parents: z.array(reference("person")).optional(),
    // ...
});

Is there a better solution like a different parser or a different way to serialize?
Edit1: Adding simpler example
import { reference, z } from 'astro:content';
// config.ts
const ZPerson = z.object({
  id: z.number({
        message: "Unique identifier of a person"
    }),
    parents: z.array(reference("person")).optional(),
});
export const ZPersonArray = z.array(ZPerson);
export const collections = {
    person: ZPersonCollection
}

# content/1.yaml
id: 1
parents: ["2"]

# content/2.yaml
id: 2

import { getCollection } from 'astro:content';
// Test file
let dbPersons = await getCollection("person");
const jsonPerson = JSON.stringify(dbPersons);

const objectPerson = JSON.parse(jsonPerson);
const persons = await ZPersonArray.parseAsync(objectPerson);


not sure I understand. please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Added simpler example

I see more code now. but what do you expect to happen? and where does the reference function come from

Sorry. I hope I added the correct imports. I dont have the original code anymore as I switch to use a DB instead of astro:content (drizzle + SQLite). This is now out of curiosity. As it may help someone else.

okay, the docs for those interested: https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/#defining-collection-references
